# Create Woocommerce product without creating api credentials

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I am creating a plugin to interact with WooCommerce.
Currently, if I want to create a product I need to generate API credentials in the WooCommerce settings and add those credentials into a form in the menu page created by my plugin which is then, in turn, saving them as `wp_options` and then accessing them when I connect to the WooCommerce rest API.
These seem like too many steps to follow for anyone else who is using the plugin and might not be too familiar with WordPress.

Is there a way to programmatically generate these credentials or even interact with WooCommerce without these credentials altogether?
This plugin will only run on WordPress and any data in it will remain on the domain it is installed. There will be no external API calls only to the WooCommerce installed on the same WordPress my plugin is installed on.

I managed to create the keys automatically with the WooCommerce auth endpoint but I can't get the keys from the callback url.

Comment: Is this from PHP or JS? If it's PHP then you can just call the main API directly, e.g. start with `WC()` to get the WooCommerce object.

Comment: Hi, thank you for responding, it's from a php file in my plugin. do I need to include some other file to get access to the WC() object or is it defined globally?

Comment: No, as long as the WooCommerce plugin is loaded WC() should be defined globally in WordPress.

Comment: Thank you so much for the info

Comment: Hi, if you have solved your problem you can write an answer and mark it as accepted so people will be able to see how it was solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.

You can directly interact with WooCommerce if you include the main woocommerce file from woocommerce/woocommerce.php

The classes I specifically used were [WC_Product](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Product.html) and [WC_Product_Query](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Product-Query.html)

With these classes, you can get existing products and create new ones. I included links to the docs for these two classes